# Set variable to retrieve in model- Sequelize

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

I have an express controller in which I want to set my current user to retrieve in sequelize virtual

```
controller ...(req, res) => {
  db.users.build({currentUser: req.body.user.id})
  db.users.set("currentUser", req.body.user.id})
}
```

On my modal I want to do:

```
type: {
  type: Sequelize.VIRTUAL,
  get() {
    let User = this.getDataValue("currentUser");
    console.log("get -> User", messageUser);
    return User
  },
},
```

What I want to obtain is a variable that I want to use inside of my models(I does not have to be just the "db.users" modal.